# How to list items vertically in GTK Iconview?

Tags: gtk, gtk3

How can we list items vertically in GTK Iconview? I want items in multiple columns, but items should be listed top-to-bottom instead of left-to-right. Iconview doesn't seem to have any property to set the orientation. Can we achieve this in some other way?

Sample code:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Items a,b,c are ordered from left-to-right. How can I order them from top-to-bottom (such that a,b,c are in the same vertical column) ?

Comment: Of course it has. If you click ont the [properties](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkIconView.html#GtkIconView.properties) you will notice that there is a propertiy called ["item-orientation”](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkIconView.html#GtkIconView--item-orientation).

Comment: It will be better if you post a code [MCVE] which we can compile and test it.

Comment: @Michi item-orientation controls the relative position of icon and text for an item, i.e. whether item label should be shown below the icon or to the right side.

Comment: @Michi added code and screenshot

Comment: I am on vacation and I can not check it. Sorry, you are right about the property I was talking. Could you please ask your question to the gnome team? http://discourse.gnome.org

Comment: Got a response from gnome team. Icon view does not support this functionality. Thanks.

Comment: I am happy to hear that. You could post it as answer with this information. It could help others as well. Happy coding 